# ActiveAdmin / Carrierwave multiple image upload display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Hello Everebody I have a problem with the display of my photos that I upload in multiple

[Error with rails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt59V.png)

you can see my different file for this upload

ActiveAdmin file

```
ActiveAdmin.register Photo do

permit_params :car_id, { photos: [] }

index do
  selectable_column
  id_column
  column "numéro voiture", :car_id
  column "Photo" do |photo|
      "<a href='#{photo.photos_urls}'><img src='#{photo.photos_urls}' width='150'></a>".html_safe
  end

  actions
end

form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :car_id
    f.input :photos, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }
  actions
end
```

photos_uploader.rb

```
 class PhotosUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^_[:word:]\.\-\+]/
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

photo.rb

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord

  mount_uploaders :photos, PhotosUploader

  belongs_to :car
end
```

car.rb

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

    mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

    has_many :photos
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your form? Pleas check if you set the attribute for mutiple files:

```
<%= form.file_field :photo, multiple: true %>
```

Also, if you are uploading files in different models, I recommend you make another uploader (one uploader for each attribute for each model). `photo` is supposed to be an attribute, not a model.

```
mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
```

For more information:
[github carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

Answer (score 0):

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :car_id
    f.input :photos, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }
  actions
end
```

my form is into active admin file

i have 2 photo uploader 1 for avatar and second for multiple photo for my car class